# First item in a drop-down list box in InfoPath 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, dropdown

I have a Drop-down field in InfoPath form. When Drop-down field is loaded I want to set the first item of the Drop-down field to a text field. Any one knows how to set first item of the Drop-down field to a text field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question means, you need the users to enter their values into  **Drop Down List** you can't do that, while there's another control **combo box**.

**Combo box** Enables users to either select a predefined value from a list of choices or type their own value, **but** this control cannot be displayed in a Web browser forms.
so When you design a browser-compatible form template, combo box controls are unavailable.

====**Workaround**====
you can Show\hide a **text box** based on a **drop down list value**, meaning for example if user selects **"Other"** a text box will Show in the form to allow users to enter their values.
Check out this link  [Hide a control based on values on the form](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/hide-a-control-based-on-values-on-the-form-0cfd584f-8e52-479d-9419-df2c4231d72e)

**==Update===========**
If your question means , that on the page loading you need to set the text box value with the default selected item in the drop down List , try the below:

1. on the ribbon , select DATA tab
2. click on form Load
3. in the Rules window click New->Action rule
4. In the rule's Run these action ->Add->Set a field's value
5. set the text box field = drop down field

[image]

hope this answer's your question

Comment: My question was to get first item out from drop-down and show it in the textbox

Comment: @SivakumarPiratheeban do you mean when user selects a value , should this value be set to the textbox? or you mean from the start before selecting the drop down ?

Comment: From the start before selecting the drop down

Comment: @SivakumarPiratheeban check the answer update